# Cannot upload photos from Picasa via Facebook uploader

Tags: facebook

I have a problem with the Facebook uploader in Picasa.

How can I solve this (see below)?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an issue with downloadable software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely check the Picasa App permissions on the Facebook side. I was able to duplicate your findings after manually mangling the permissions the app got.

You might need to remove the Picasa app first and then re-authenticate it via the Facebook Upload feature in the Picasa uploader.

Comment: how to remove? how to manage its permissions? Couldn't find both of these

Comment: You can remove Facebook permissions for the app by clicking the `x` next to the application on the [Facebook Applications page](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)